# Is there a 'queue' behind any given Mule Flow that can be configured to be persistent?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I thought I read somewhere that every Flow is backed by a queue of sorts.  Is this true? Can this queue be configured (e.g. persistence, etc.).  I'm looking at my options for storing messages that failed to deliver for one reason or another.  I don't currently have a JMS server available, and was hoping to avoid using an embedded instance of ActiveMQ for the moment, if possible.  If the queues backing Mule flows are not configurable, I'm guessing my next best option is a VM queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a processing strategy for your flow that backs it with a SEDA queue. You can configure this queue to be backed by a persistent object store.

Read for more info: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Flow+Processing+Strategies#FlowProcessingStrategies-Fine-TuningaProcessingStrategy